# Proving rank of matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

$A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrix. rank($A$) = $n-1$. rank($B$) = $n$. I want to show $rank(AB) = n-1$.

A solution provided to me is:

We want to find the N($AB$), the null space of $AB$. To find the N($AB$), find $ABx=0$. We can write this as $Ay=0$, where $Bx = y$. So $x = B^{-1}y$. So N($AB$) = $B^{-1}N(A)$.

So I'm confused. First and foremost, how does this show that the rank of $AB$ = $n-1$? I'm trying to get someone to explain this proof.

Comment: $B$ has a full rank, so it is invertible. Thus rank$(AB) = $ rank$(A)$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for every invertible matrix $P$ and any matrix $B$ we have $$\text{rank}(PB)=\text{rank}(B)$$

*Proof* 
$$\begin{align}\text{rank}(PB)=k &\iff \dim\left\{x|PBx=0\ \ x\in \mathbb{R}^n\right\}=n-k\\
& \iff \dim\left\{x|P^{-1}(PBx)=0\ \  x\in \mathbb{R}^n\right\}=n-k\\
& \iff \dim\left\{x|Bx=0\ \  x\in \mathbb{R}^n\right\}=n-k\\
&\iff \text{rank}(B)=k \end{align}$$

Note that this follows from the equivalences:
$$(PBx)=0\iff P^{-1}(PBx)=0\iff Bx=0 $$

Comment: So $N(AB)$ = $N(A)$?

Comment: Yes we have $N(AB)=B^{-1}N(A)$ so that the dimension is the same because an invertible matrix does not chnage the dimension of any space (by multiplication)

Comment: probably silly question, but why include the $B^{-1}$ at all?

Comment: Second question: since the rank(AB) = n-1, can we infer that the nullity of $AB$ = 1?

Comment: yes you can they are equivalent

Answer (score 1):

(1) Since $A$ has rank $n-1$ so there exists $y\neq 0$ : $Ay=0$. And since $B$ has rank $n$ so there exists $x\neq 0$ s.t. $Bx=y$. So $$ ABx=Ay=0$$ So $AB$ has nontrivial kernel. So ${\rm rank}\ (AB)\leq n-1$

(2) Assume that $z\neq 0$ is another kernel of $AB$ s.t. $z\neq cx$ where $$x\neq 0\in {\rm ker} \ AB$$ Then $Bz\neq 0$ but $ABz=0$ Hence $A$ has a kernel $Bz$. Since $A$ has rank $n-1$ then $$ Bz=cy$$ for some $c$. So $z=cB^{-1}y=cx$. Contradiction.

Comment: What did you contradict?

Comment: I editted. Notice the assumption in (2)